# Asp.net web api routing issue?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am using web api in my mvc application. I have a problem while calling web api using jquey.get function. Consider the following scenario:

I have 2 controller name:

1. HomeMVCController
2. TestAPIController *(using mvc style routing i.e. api/{controller}/{action}/{id})*

HomeMVC controller contains 2 actions

1. Index
2. About

TestAPI controller contains 1 action

1. Get

When i was on Index view of HomeMVC controller i.e.

```
http://localhost:1025/Home
```

and when i call `$.get("api/TestAPI/Get")` from the browser it returns the expected json response.

But when i was on About view of HomeMVC controller i.e.

```
http://localhost:1025/Home/About
```

and when i call `$.get("api/TestAPI/Get")` from the browser it returns error, resource not found, and the resource it is trying to locate is:

```
http://localhost:1025/Home/About/api/TestAPI/Get
```

instead of

```
http://localhost:1025/api/TestAPI/Get
```

Why browser added *Home/About* in the url to api and why it is not added *Home/Index* when i was on *Index* view. On *Index* view why api call is working as expected and why not working on *About* view ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used a [relative url](http://www.webreference.com/html/tutorial2/3.html) when you should be using an absolute url.

You should instead use an absolute url by doing:

```
$.get("@Url.RouteUrl("@Url.RouteUrl("DefaultApi", new {httproute="", controller="TestAPI", action="Get"}))
```

If you want to keep your javascript in separate js files (and not in the razor files) what you can do is have an initialize method that is called from a razor view.

The .js file:

```
var myPageJsUrls = {};

var MyPageInitialize = function(getItemsUrl, saveItemUrl, editItemUrl){
    myPageJsUrls.getItemsUrl = getItemsUrl;
    myPageJsUrls.saveItemUrl = saveItemUrl;
    myPageJsUrls.editItemUrl = editItemUrl;
}


var getItems = function(){
    return $.get(myPageUrls.getItemsUrl);
}

...
```

In the razor file:

```
<script>
    myPageInitialize('@Url.Action("AllItems", "Items")', '@Url.RouteUrl("DefaultApi", new {httproute="", controller="TestAPI"}, ...)
</script>
```

Comment: but you are using server syntax for generating absolute url, how i can using this in js file ??

Comment: What I usually do is I have an Initialize method that is called from a Razor view and with all the urls the javascript needs, e.g.: `Initialize({testApiGet: '@Url.RouteUrl(...)', GetItems: '@Url.Action(...)'})`. I'll update the answer with an example